# What smart thermostat can be used for this gas heater?

Tags: thermostat

I am located in eastern Europe and smart thermostats aren't a thing here. So there are no people with experience in installing these.

I really would love to use something like google nest or ecobee with this one, but I am not sure of compatibility...

I already have google nest (ebay purchase from U.S.) but I couldn't figure out how to hook it up, also I cannot choose my country/city in the menu of google nest :| So no weather data I imagine.

I found two pdf docs, but they are in Italian:

https://www.italtherm.it/admin/uploads/LIBRETTO_CITY_CLASS_2478.pdf
https://www.italtherm.it/admin/uploads/SCHEDA_TECNICA_CITY_CLASS_2127.pdf

These are thermostat photos, and a wire:

[image: Air processing unit with LCD display]

[image: 230 VAC warning tag]

[image: Black thermal sensor on end of wire]

I would love to try with google nest I already have. And as last resort purchase ecobee, but this time I would like to be sure its doable.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: The truth is I don't know a word of Italian, but.. to the extent that it looks kind of like Spanish, I had a go at reading the manual. Page 53 mentions a thermostat can be connected to the TA input and elsewhere it mentions the heater can be configured for a thermostat at TA2 or AUX. It seems shorting the pins together on TA input should start a heat cycle. Can you confirm? If there's a connector on the end of the wire in the picture, that may be the TA input.

Comment: Yes: see where the wire connects. Also: in the best case, to make a North America style thermostat work with your heater, you'll need to also obtain a 24 volt transformer and relay. We can suggest how to wire everything, but if it already sounds like too much trouble, just say so.

Comment: @GregHill Something like this? https://www.amazon.com/Aube-RC840T-240-Switching-Electric-Transformer/dp/B0037MXM1C/ref=pd_bxgy_img_sccl_1/131-3601477-3232262?pd_rd_w=DXLsW&pf_rd_p=6b3eefea-7b16-43e9-bc45-2e332cbf99da&pf_rd_r=36D1X399ADR2S9G30M4P&pd_rd_r=dbc190c8-c5a8-4675-9572-dffa33eafcca&pd_rd_wg=uBQRv&pd_rd_i=B0037MXM1C&th=1

Comment: @GregHill Why do I need relay? The cable (maybe TA) I am holding in hand says don't attach anything with 230v, also from what I get remote kit page 56 - says that it doesn't need batteries cause cable is providing low tension from the heater itself.

Comment: How are normal thermostats hooked up where you live?  What voltage and how do they work?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine People don't use thermostats here :( they go to the heater and use the knob. I couldn't find a technician who could answer these questions.

Comment: @GregHill I can confirm, the wire is indeed attached to TA from the docs. It also says that there is low tension in the wires, and mentions SELV (Safety Extra Low Voltage) - does this give any clue?

Comment: From my limited understanding of the manual I get the idea that the TA input is for a temperature sensor _or possibly a thermostat_. Seems TA2 and aux can be configured through the setup menu as extra temperature inputs. If I were in your position I'd turn off the heater, disconnect the TA cable, turn on the heater, and test what happens when the TA terminals are shorted together with a wire. There may be some risk of damage to the electronics but the risk seems quite low. I'd try it if the heater were mine, but the decision is up to you!

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a heater that has a thermostat built into it (not a great design).  You will need to read the installation manual to get insights on how to attach an external thermostat, and what voltage that thermostat acts on.  Heaters with thermostats *on them* are generally cheap units, so the easiest path may be a less cheap unit. (noting that you already dropped hundreds of euro on a Nest).